# Single User cannot send email to public folder - exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, public-folders, ndr

I have a single internal user who is receiving the following NDR when sending mail to a mail enabled public folder. It is fine for all other users, internal and external. I'm waiting to hear back from the user to try and delete the cached version of the email address from Outlook and also test from OWA to see if they see the same result.

```
Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:
Public Folder (public.folder@domain.com)
There's a problem with the recipient's mailbox. Please try resending the message. If the problem continues, please contact your helpdesk.

Diagnostic information for administrators:
Generating server: server.domain.worldwide
public.folder@domain.com

#554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Deliver.Exception:AccessDeniedException.MapiExceptionNotAuthorized; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot complete delivery-time processing. 16.55847:92110000, 17.43559:000000009E02000000000000BB00000000000000, 255.23226:C42F0000, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:0E000000, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:9E000000, 255.17082:D6040000, 0.18273:00000000, 4.21921:D6040000, 255.27962:FA000000, 255.1494:43000000, 255.1238:0F010480, 6.21970:0F0104800B003A660F010480, 4.3010:0F010480, 4.3010:0F010480, 4.3650:0F010480, 4.3010:0F010480, 4.3010:0F010480, 4.3650:0F010480, 4.23921:EC030000, 6.21970:0F0104800300C4660F010480, 4.23921:EC030000, 6.21970:0F0104800201E13FB0840110, 4.23921:EC030000, 6.21970:0F010480030060671A010480, 0.22086:0F010480, 0.26000:0300DD3F, 4.4580:05000780, 0.26640:0F010480, 4.4408:05000780, 4.7637:D8040000, 0.49797:40001900, 4.5093:D6040000, 4.5318:D6040000, 4.10104:D6040000, 0.57449:0F010480, 4.6025:05000780, 4.5257:05000780, 4.4606:D6040000, 255.1750:00000000, 0.26849:0F010480, 255.21817:D6040000 ##
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the results of the tests you have asked it is difficult to say exactly what the issue is.

On the face of it, the error usually means what it says - access denied, indicating the user doesn't have permissions to send to the folder. 
Remember being able to send to the folder is different to being able to view it, and internal users are authenticated users, which is different to external senders in the permissions required.

Simon.

Answer (score 0):

Your error description isn't too detailed.

But it seems like a permission problem.
Check, if a administrator can send such a mail.
If you can do that, you need to look over permissions for said user.